# Bootstrap Password Revealer Got Into Bug

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

A Bootstrap password revealer that makes my PC hang when I hover the eye button. It  adds automatically an input even though there's no codes to add an input. 
The input has automatically increase, it makes my bowser hang on and then my whole PC next.
What is the possible reason and solution for this? This causes my PC hang.

JSFIDDLE: https://jsfiddle.net/aice09/76b99w4m/

```js
//Password Revealer
$(".reveal").mousedown(function() {
    $(".pwd").replaceWith($('.pwd').clone().attr('type', 'text'));
  })
  .mouseup(function() {
    $(".pwd").replaceWith($('.pwd').clone().attr('type', 'password'));
  })
  .mouseout(function() {
    $(".pwd").replaceWith($('.pwd').clone().attr('type', 'password'));
  });
```

```css
.btn-primary {
  color: #0275d8;
  background-image: none;
  background-color: transparent;
  border-color: #0275d8;
}

.btn-primary:hover {
  background-color: #0275d8;
  color: white;
  border-color: #0275d8;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.3.min.jshttps://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.3.min.js"></script>

<div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-12 col-lg-12">
  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="em_password">Password</label>
    <div class="input-group">
      <input id="em_password" name="em_password" type="password" class="form-control pwd" maxlength="8">
      <span class="input-group-btn">
                                        <button class="btn btn-default reveal" type="button"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-eye-open"></i></button>
                                    </span>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<!-- // Modal -->
```

Comment: Did you really need to include all of that HTML in the question? 95% of it is irrelevant. Possible hint: how many elements does the `".pwd"` selector match?

Comment: Question codes has been edited. Only add the needed part.

Comment: I added an answer that reveals the password on click, but not sure if that's what you're going for or if you want the event functionality in your OP. It's kind of unintuitive, but if so, you could just change the `attr` in those events, no need to clone. And target the unique password field that holds the password, not all `.pwd`'s https://jsfiddle.net/76b99w4m/2/

Comment: @MichaelCoker, thanks for your answer. By the way, I debug my codes using the first answer with my question. An I just use hover for my fuction.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would just set the `type` of the password input to `text` when you click on `.reveal`

```js
//Password Revealer
$(".reveal").on('click',function() {
 $('#em_password').attr('type','text');
})
```

```css
.btn-primary {
  color: #0275d8;
  background-image: none;
  background-color: transparent;
  border-color: #0275d8;
}

.btn-primary:hover {
  background-color: #0275d8;
  color: white;
  border-color: #0275d8;
}

.btn-success {
  color: #fff;
  background-color: #5cb85c;
  border-color: #5cb85c;
}

.btn-success:hover {
  color: #fff;
  background-color: #449d44;
  border-color: #419641;
}

.btn-info {
  color: #fff;
  background-color: #5bc0de;
  border-color: #5bc0de;
}

.btn-info:hover {
  color: #fff;
  background-color: #31b0d5;
  border-color: #2aabd2;
}

.btn-warning {
  color: #fff;
  background-color: #f0ad4e;
  border-color: #f0ad4e;
}

.btn-warning:hover {
  color: #fff;
  background-color: #ec971f;
  border-color: #eb9316;
}

.btn-danger {
  color: #fff;
  background-color: #d9534f;
  border-color: #d9534f;
}

.btn-danger:hover {
  color: #fff;
  background-color: #c9302c;
  border-color: #c12e2a;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.3.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div id="navigation"></div>

<!-- Content Section -->
<div class="container-fluid">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-12 col-lg-12">
      <h1>Employee</h1>
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-12 col-lg-12">
      <div class="pull-right">
        <button class="btn btn-success addnewemployee" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#add_new_record_modal">Add New Job</button>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-12 col-lg-12 sales_individual_tb">
      <div class="records_content"></div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<!-- /Content Section -->

<!-- Bootstrap Modals -->
<!-- Modal - Add New Record/User -->
<div class="modal fade bs-example-modal-lg" id="add_new_record_modal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel">
  <div class="modal-dialog modal-lg" role="document">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
        <h4 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel">Add New Employee</h4>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
        <div class="row">
          <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-4 col-lg-4">
            <div class="form-group">
              <label for="em_firstname">First Name</label>
              <input type="text" id="em_firstname" placeholder="First Name" class="form-control" />
            </div>
          </div>

          <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-4 col-lg-4">
            <div class="form-group">
              <label for="em_middlename">Middle Name</label>
              <input type="text" id="em_middlename" placeholder="Middle Name" class="form-control" />
            </div>
          </div>

          <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-4 col-lg-4">
            <div class="form-group">
              <label for="em_lastname">Last Name</label>
              <input type="text" id="em_lastname" placeholder="Last Name" class="form-control" />
            </div>
          </div>

          <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-4 col-lg-4">
            <div class="form-group">
              <label for="em_id">System ID</label>
              <input type="text" id="em_id" placeholder="System ID" class="form-control" readonly />
            </div>
          </div>

          <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-8 col-lg-8">
            <div class="form-group">
              <label for="em_email">Email</label>
              <input type="text" id="em_email" placeholder="Email" class="form-control" />
            </div>
          </div>

          <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-4 col-lg-4">
            <div class="form-group">
              <label for="em_position">Position</label>
              <select name="em_position" id="em_position" class="form-control" required="required">
                <option value="Position 1">Position 1</option>
                <option value="Position 2">Position 2</option>
                <option value="Position 3">Position 3</option>
              </select>
            </div>
          </div>

          <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-4 col-lg-4">
            <div class="form-group">
              <label for="em_department">Department</label>
              <select name="em_department" id="em_department" class="form-control" required="required">
                <option value="Department 1">Department 1</option>
                <option value="Department 2">Department 2</option>
                <option value="Department 3">Department 3</option>
                <option value="Department 4">Department 4</option>
              </select>
            </div>
          </div>

          <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-4 col-lg-4">
            <div class="form-group">
              <label for="em_password">Password</label>
              <div class="input-group">
                <input id="em_password" name="em_password" type="password" class="form-control pwd" maxlength="8">
                <span class="input-group-btn">
                                        <button class="btn btn-default reveal" type="button"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-eye-open"></i></button>
                                    </span>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Cancel</button>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" onclick="addRecord()">Add Record</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<!-- // Modal -->

<!-- Modal - Update User details -->
<div class="modal fade bs-example-modal-lg" id="update_user_modal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel">
  <div class="modal-dialog modal-lg" role="document">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
        <h4 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel">Update</h4>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
        <div class="row">
          <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-4 col-lg-4">
            <div class="form-group">
              <label for="em_firstname">First Name</label>
              <input type="text" id="update_em_firstname" placeholder="First Name" class="form-control" />
            </div>
          </div>

          <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-4 col-lg-4">
            <div class="form-group">
              <label for="em_middlename">Middle Name</label>
              <input type="text" id="update_em_middlename" placeholder="Middle Name" class="form-control" />
            </div>
          </div>

          <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-4 col-lg-4">
            <div class="form-group">
              <label for="em_lastname">Last Name</label>
              <input type="text" id="update_em_lastname" placeholder="Last Name" class="form-control" />
            </div>
          </div>

          <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-4 col-lg-4">
            <div class="form-group">
              <label for="em_id">System ID</label>
              <input type="text" id="update_em_id" placeholder="System ID" class="form-control" readonly />
            </div>
          </div>

          <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-8 col-lg-8">
            <div class="form-group">
              <label for="em_email">Email</label>
              <input type="text" id="update_em_email" placeholder="Email" class="form-control" />
            </div>
          </div>

          <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-4 col-lg-4">
            <div class="form-group">
              <label for="em_position">Position</label>
              <select name="update_em_position" id="update_em_position" class="form-control" required="required">
                <option value="Position 1">Position 1</option>
                <option value="Position 2">Position 2</option>
                <option value="Position 3">Position 3</option>
              </select>
            </div>
          </div>

          <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-4 col-lg-4">
            <div class="form-group">
              <label for="em_department">Department</label>
              <select name="update_em_department" id="update_em_department" class="form-control" required="required">
                <option value="Department 1">Department 1</option>
                <option value="Department 2">Department 2</option>
                <option value="Department 3">Department 3</option>
                <option value="Department 4">Department 4</option>
              </select>
            </div>
          </div>

          <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-4 col-lg-4">
            <div class="form-group">
              <label for="em_password">Password</label>
              <div class="input-group">
                <input id="update_em_password" name="update_em_password" type="password" class="form-control pwd" maxlength="8" value="11">
                <span class="input-group-btn">
                                        <button class="btn btn-default reveal" type="button"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-eye-open"></i></button>
                                    </span>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Cancel</button>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" onclick="UpdateUserDetails()">Save Changes</button>
        <input type="hidden" id="hidden_user_id">
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Here's how I would do it with your original events.

```js
//Password Revealer
$passwd = $('#em_password');

$(".reveal").mousedown(function() {
    $passwd.attr('type', 'text');
  })
  .mouseup(function() {
    $passwd.attr('type', 'password');
  })
  .mouseout(function() {
    $passwd.attr('type', 'password');
});
```

```css
.btn-primary {
  color: #0275d8;
  background-image: none;
  background-color: transparent;
  border-color: #0275d8;
}

.btn-primary:hover {
  background-color: #0275d8;
  color: white;
  border-color: #0275d8;
}

.btn-success {
  color: #fff;
  background-color: #5cb85c;
  border-color: #5cb85c;
}

.btn-success:hover {
  color: #fff;
  background-color: #449d44;
  border-color: #419641;
}

.btn-info {
  color: #fff;
  background-color: #5bc0de;
  border-color: #5bc0de;
}

.btn-info:hover {
  color: #fff;
  background-color: #31b0d5;
  border-color: #2aabd2;
}

.btn-warning {
  color: #fff;
  background-color: #f0ad4e;
  border-color: #f0ad4e;
}

.btn-warning:hover {
  color: #fff;
  background-color: #ec971f;
  border-color: #eb9316;
}

.btn-danger {
  color: #fff;
  background-color: #d9534f;
  border-color: #d9534f;
}

.btn-danger:hover {
  color: #fff;
  background-color: #c9302c;
  border-color: #c12e2a;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.3.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div id="navigation"></div>

<!-- Content Section -->
<div class="container-fluid">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-12 col-lg-12">
      <h1>Employee</h1>
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-12 col-lg-12">
      <div class="pull-right">
        <button class="btn btn-success addnewemployee" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#add_new_record_modal">Add New Job</button>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-12 col-lg-12 sales_individual_tb">
      <div class="records_content"></div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<!-- /Content Section -->

<!-- Bootstrap Modals -->
<!-- Modal - Add New Record/User -->
<div class="modal fade bs-example-modal-lg" id="add_new_record_modal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel">
  <div class="modal-dialog modal-lg" role="document">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
        <h4 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel">Add New Employee</h4>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
        <div class="row">
          <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-4 col-lg-4">
            <div class="form-group">
              <label for="em_firstname">First Name</label>
              <input type="text" id="em_firstname" placeholder="First Name" class="form-control" />
            </div>
          </div>

          <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-4 col-lg-4">
            <div class="form-group">
              <label for="em_middlename">Middle Name</label>
              <input type="text" id="em_middlename" placeholder="Middle Name" class="form-control" />
            </div>
          </div>

          <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-4 col-lg-4">
            <div class="form-group">
              <label for="em_lastname">Last Name</label>
              <input type="text" id="em_lastname" placeholder="Last Name" class="form-control" />
            </div>
          </div>

          <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-4 col-lg-4">
            <div class="form-group">
              <label for="em_id">System ID</label>
              <input type="text" id="em_id" placeholder="System ID" class="form-control" readonly />
            </div>
          </div>

          <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-8 col-lg-8">
            <div class="form-group">
              <label for="em_email">Email</label>
              <input type="text" id="em_email" placeholder="Email" class="form-control" />
            </div>
          </div>

          <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-4 col-lg-4">
            <div class="form-group">
              <label for="em_position">Position</label>
              <select name="em_position" id="em_position" class="form-control" required="required">
                <option value="Position 1">Position 1</option>
                <option value="Position 2">Position 2</option>
                <option value="Position 3">Position 3</option>
              </select>
            </div>
          </div>

          <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-4 col-lg-4">
            <div class="form-group">
              <label for="em_department">Department</label>
              <select name="em_department" id="em_department" class="form-control" required="required">
                <option value="Department 1">Department 1</option>
                <option value="Department 2">Department 2</option>
                <option value="Department 3">Department 3</option>
                <option value="Department 4">Department 4</option>
              </select>
            </div>
          </div>

          <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-4 col-lg-4">
            <div class="form-group">
              <label for="em_password">Password</label>
              <div class="input-group">
                <input id="em_password" name="em_password" type="password" class="form-control pwd" maxlength="8">
                <span class="input-group-btn">
                                        <button class="btn btn-default reveal" type="button"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-eye-open"></i></button>
                                    </span>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Cancel</button>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" onclick="addRecord()">Add Record</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<!-- // Modal -->

<!-- Modal - Update User details -->
<div class="modal fade bs-example-modal-lg" id="update_user_modal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel">
  <div class="modal-dialog modal-lg" role="document">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
        <h4 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel">Update</h4>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
        <div class="row">
          <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-4 col-lg-4">
            <div class="form-group">
              <label for="em_firstname">First Name</label>
              <input type="text" id="update_em_firstname" placeholder="First Name" class="form-control" />
            </div>
          </div>

          <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-4 col-lg-4">
            <div class="form-group">
              <label for="em_middlename">Middle Name</label>
              <input type="text" id="update_em_middlename" placeholder="Middle Name" class="form-control" />
            </div>
          </div>

          <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-4 col-lg-4">
            <div class="form-group">
              <label for="em_lastname">Last Name</label>
              <input type="text" id="update_em_lastname" placeholder="Last Name" class="form-control" />
            </div>
          </div>

          <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-4 col-lg-4">
            <div class="form-group">
              <label for="em_id">System ID</label>
              <input type="text" id="update_em_id" placeholder="System ID" class="form-control" readonly />
            </div>
          </div>

          <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-8 col-lg-8">
            <div class="form-group">
              <label for="em_email">Email</label>
              <input type="text" id="update_em_email" placeholder="Email" class="form-control" />
            </div>
          </div>

          <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-4 col-lg-4">
            <div class="form-group">
              <label for="em_position">Position</label>
              <select name="update_em_position" id="update_em_position" class="form-control" required="required">
                <option value="Position 1">Position 1</option>
                <option value="Position 2">Position 2</option>
                <option value="Position 3">Position 3</option>
              </select>
            </div>
          </div>

          <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-4 col-lg-4">
            <div class="form-group">
              <label for="em_department">Department</label>
              <select name="update_em_department" id="update_em_department" class="form-control" required="required">
                <option value="Department 1">Department 1</option>
                <option value="Department 2">Department 2</option>
                <option value="Department 3">Department 3</option>
                <option value="Department 4">Department 4</option>
              </select>
            </div>
          </div>

          <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-4 col-lg-4">
            <div class="form-group">
              <label for="em_password">Password</label>
              <div class="input-group">
                <input id="update_em_password" name="update_em_password" type="password" class="form-control pwd" maxlength="8" value="11">
                <span class="input-group-btn">
                                        <button class="btn btn-default reveal" type="button"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-eye-open"></i></button>
                                    </span>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Cancel</button>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" onclick="UpdateUserDetails()">Save Changes</button>
        <input type="hidden" id="hidden_user_id">
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Why would that work better than the OP's code? What about the apparent requirement to change the type back again?

Comment: @nnnnnn I'm assuming that's what they were trying to do. They accepted my answer so I'm assuming they were just trying to reveal the password on click. Also added a comment to the OP enabling the change on the events they specified. https://jsfiddle.net/76b99w4m/2/

Comment: @MichaelCoker. Thanks for your answer. It helps me a lot. Rather than bug type code I used before that cause my PC down. By the way I use hover rather than onclick function '   `$(".reveal").hover(function(){ $('#em_password').attr('type','text');$('#update_em_password').attr('type','text');},function(){$('#em_password').attr('type','password');$('#update_em_password').attr('type','password');  });`